# Why is variable behaving differently outside loop?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, while-loop

if i run this code:

```
def numbers_in_lists(string):
    next_number = 0
    count = 0
    final_list = []
    while count < len(string):
        number = int(string[count])
        if number > next_number:
            final_list.append(number)
            new = []
            next_number = number
        else:
            new.append(number)
            if new not in final_list:
                final_list.append(new)
        count += 1
    print final_list


#testcases
string = '543987'
result = [5,[4,3],9,[8,7]]
print repr(string), numbers_in_lists(string) == result
```

i get this answer:

```
'543987' [5, [4, 3], 9, [8, 7]]
False
```

but if i put the `number` variable outside of the `while` loop like this:

```
def numbers_in_lists(string):
    next_number = 0
    count = 0
    final_list = []
    number = int(string[count])
    while count < len(string):
        if number > next_number:
            final_list.append(number)
            new = []
            next_number = number
        else:
            new.append(number)
            if new not in final_list:
                final_list.append(new)
        count += 1
    print final_list
```

i get this answer:

```
'543987' [5, [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]
False
```

I am a beginner and i have looked everywhere for the explanation as to why the `number` variable behaves differently outside of the loop? Also, why are the other variables ok outside of the loop but not `number` variable?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thankyou. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare `number` as

```
number = int(string[count])
```

So when

```
count = 0
```

This means that `number` will be the first character of your string (position `[0]`) converted to `int`. If you do not update `number` within your loop, it will never change. In your first version of the code, `number` is in your `while` loop.

```
while count < len(string):
    number = int(string[count])
    # more code
    count += 1
```

Note at the end of the loop, you increment `count`. This means at the beginning of the next iteration, `count` now is incremented, so `number` will take on the value of the next character in your string.

A common misconception for beginners is that a variable is somehow "bound" to another variable. For example:

```
>>> a = 5
>>> b = a
>>> b
5

>>> a = 7
>>> b
5
```

See, even though `a` changed values from `5` to `7`, `b` doesn't change because it is not "bound" to that variable in any way. The line `b = a` means "take the value from `a` and assign it to `b`" after that, `b` doesn't care what happens to `a`.

Answer (score 1):

The `number = int(string[count])` uses the value of `count` assigned outside the loop which is the first character `index 0`, it will never change outside the loop, so you will always get the original value appended which is the first character.

Using `number = int(string[count])` inside the loop you are reassigning  `number` to the value of the element at `index count`  each time so you get a different part of the input string appended each time.

Once you enter the `while loop` any values you change that were defined **outside** of the loop will not change outside that loop, you must reassign the value **inside** the loop.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The thing i don't understand is that i am changing the value of count which is defined outside of the loop. So i don't understand why number would not change value also, if count has changed value.

Comment: yes but you only assign a value to number once outside the loop, count may change inside the loop but the value of number that you assigned  outside the loop does not

Answer (score 1):

I get that you are a beginner. Here is a rewrite that should help you with some useful python idioms and constructs:

```
def numbers_in_lists(string):
    numbers = [int(c) for c in string]
    next_number = -1
    final_list = []
    for number in numbers:
        if number > next_number:
            final_list.append(number)
            final_list.append([])
            next_number = number
        else:
            final_list[-1].append(number)
    final_list = [x for x in final_list if x != []]
    print final_list
```

First, be suspicious when you have a `while-loop` and a counter. You can replace it with a `for-loop` that iterates over all the items.

Since this code operates on integers, not characters in a string, let's translate them all at once using a list comprehension:

```
numbers = [int(c) for c in string]
```

This creates a list that has all the characters translated to integers.

By setting `next_number = -1`, we ensure that all numbers in `numbers` will be greater. In particular, the first element will be greater.

When we find a `number` that exceeds our last maximum, `next_number`, we add `number` *and* a bucket to put succeeding numbers less than `number` into:

```
        if number > next_number:
            final_list.append(number)
            final_list.append([])
            next_number = number
```

That means when we add 5, final_list looks like this:

```
[5, []]
```

And when `number` is `4` and `3`, they get added properly:

```
[5, [4]]
[5, [4, 3]]
```

How does that happen? This code does it:

```
        else:
            final_list[-1].append(number)
```

Here we do not append to `final_list`; we append to the last list in `final_list`, `final_list[-1]`.

But what if our sequence was just `5`? Then at the end of the loop, `final_list` would look like this:

```
[5, []]
```

In that case, we want to trim out all empty lists, so we do it like this:

```
final_list = [x for x in final_list if x != []]
```

This says, "make final_list into a list that has all elements of final_list except those that are empty lists."

Good luck with learning python. I hope you find it rewarding.